# How do I display, update and delete my cells?

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I am taking a class to create a client list iOS app and connect it to Realm, I am not a great coder and my online school teaches poorly, so Youtube is my teacher most of the time. I am working off a Realm app video but am unsure how to do things past where they end. The app so far is a tableview, when I select the plus button in the top right corner, it opens a field to enter the client's name, address, city, state and zip code. when I click save it then stores the info to Realm and displays a Subtitle cell with the client's name and city. I would like to be able to delete the cell by swiping and also be able to view the full contents of the cell  and update the cell. If anyone can offer any assistance I would be very grateful. Please see my ViewController below:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ContactItem: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var addressOne = ""
    @objc dynamic var addressTwo = ""
    @objc dynamic var city = ""
    @objc dynamic var state = ""
    @objc dynamic var zipCode = ""
    @objc dynamic var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.generate()
    convenience init(name: String, addressOne: String, addressTwo: String, city: String, state: String, zipCode: String, _id: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.addressOne = addressOne
        self.addressTwo = addressTwo
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zipCode = zipCode
    }
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    let mike = ContactItem(name: "Mike", addressOne: "234 Maple Lane", addressTwo: "", city: "Ankeny", state: "Ohio", zipCode: "45665", _id: "0")
    
    var people = try! Realm().objects(ContactItem.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true)
    var realm = try! Realm()
    var db: OpaquePointer?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        if realm.isEmpty {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(mike)
            }
        }
        let path = realm.configuration.fileURL?.path
        print("Path: \(String(describing: path))")
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Client", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        //when the user clicks the add button, present them with a dialog to enter the task name.
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: {
            alert -> Void in
            let nameField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
            let addOneField = alertController.textFields![1] as UITextField
            let addTwoField = alertController.textFields![2] as UITextField
            let cityField = alertController.textFields![3] as UITextField
            let stateField = alertController.textFields![4] as UITextField
            let zipField = alertController.textFields![5] as UITextField
            
            //Create a new Task with the text that the user entered.
            let newPerson = ContactItem(name: nameField.text!, addressOne: addOneField.text!, addressTwo: addTwoField.text!, city: cityField.text!, state: stateField.text!, zipCode: zipField.text!, _id: "")
            
            //Any writes to the Realm must occur in a write block
            try! self.realm.write {
                //Add the Task to the Realm. That's it!
                self.realm.add(newPerson)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                
            }
        }))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {
            (nameField: UITextField!) -> Void in nameField.placeholder = "Enter Client Name"
        })
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {
            (addOneField: UITextField!) -> Void in addOneField.placeholder = "Enter First Address Line"
        })
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {
            (addTwoField: UITextField!) -> Void in addTwoField.placeholder = "Enter Second Address Line"
        })
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {
            (cityField: UITextField!) -> Void in cityField.placeholder = "Enter City"
        })
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {
            (stateField: UITextField!) -> Void in stateField.placeholder = "Enter State"
        })
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {
            (zipField: UITextField!) -> Void in zipField.placeholder = "Enter Zip Code"
        })
        
        //Show dialog.
        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
        
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return people.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = people[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = people[indexPath.row].city
        return cell
    }
    

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. There may be some garbage code in there, I was trying a lot of different things before so I might have accidentally left some confusing code. I apologize for the mess.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First, you have a bunch of different questions rolled into one. Here on SO, stick to one question per question to keep answers short and specific. Second, only you know what you're trying to do or what the issue is; stating *how to display my tableview cell content besides the preview* is vague as we don't know what 'the preview' means. There are a number of coding issues in the code but we went to clearly understand what the problem is. Lastly, asking for a tutor is off topic and will likely get your question closed, so don't do that. Clarify the question and we'll take a look.

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you for the feedback, I tried to  clean up my wording and vagueness. Thank you for the feedback. I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: The question and code is much clearer now. At first glance, I am not seeing anything really wrong with the code. Your question states two objectives 1) Edit an exiting user and 2) delete a user. Now you need to add an *Edit* button to the UI, which highlights when a user is selected. That button press would call code in an `editButtonTapped` function where you pass the existing user to the subview and populate it. Upon closing, update the user in Realm. Likewise you need to add the code to handle swiping. Is there something wrong with the code in the question or if not... what is the question?

Comment: my problem is I don't know what the right code is to perform these tasks, like I said, most of my "schooling" is from Youtube. I get little to no help from school so I was hoping someone on here could help me figure out the coding needed to perform the edit and delete buttons. I tried to carry over similar code for a different project but it didn't carry over well and I ended up making things more confusing.

Comment: Your *Edit* will work similar to add but with an edit, you should pass the exiting data to the second viewController to populate the fields. There are a *lot* of examples here on SO. [Pass Data To ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5Dhow+to+pass+data+to+another+viewController). There are also examples of how to [Swipe To Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5DUITableView+swipe+To+Delete). There are also hundreds of hits when searching the internet for UITableView Tutorial which will also help you understand those tasks.